# Magento - Dynamic content in left panel of cms pages

Tags: magento, content-management-system, e-commerce

I am using Magento 1.4.1.1 to build an online shop for my client, where he wants to have a left-side menu for some cms pages. The menu has the following characteristics:

1. The links in the menu are themselves cms pages.
2. The menu itself shall be a cms page.
3. The links in menu will be based on what cms page has been requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [static CMS block](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-create-and-edit-static-blocks/). Use as many blocks as you like, a block can include other blocks with the code shown at the bottom of that link.

Include them in each CMS page's [XML layout](http://snipplr.com/view/19549/magento-display-static-blocks-with-custom-layout-update/).